# Calling image picker from nested fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm invoking an image picker from a nested Fragment with the code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
```

It correctly shows the image picker, but when I click on an image instead of displaying the nested fragment, it displays the parent fragment instead. Does anybody know why? The passage from the Parent to the nested fragment is done with the code

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.replace(R.id.parent_root, NestedFragment.newInstance());
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: can you post the code inside onActivityResult ??

Comment: that seems irrelevant because the same fact happens even if I never call that method.

Comment: not sure..just a try..check whether you have given super.onActivityResult inside parent fragment's onActivityResult ?